# Uniqueness of solutions of Young differential equations

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, rough-paths

Consider the following one dimensional Young differential equation:
\begin{align*}
&Y_t=\int_0^t Y_s dX_s,\quad t\in[0,1];\\
&Y_0=0.
\end{align*}

Here the driving process $X$ is a bounded functions $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, which is $\beta$-Holder with $\beta<1/2$.

If $Y$ is an $\alpha$-Holder function, $\alpha>1-\beta$, then this equation is well defined (because the integral then becomes just the Young integral).

Question: how to prove that the only solution to this equation in the class of $\alpha$-Holder functions is $Y\equiv0$?

Warning: note that $\beta<1/2$! If $\beta>1/2$, then this result is standard, but what to do if $\beta<1/2$?

---

**Failed solution attempt**

Denote by $[X]_{\beta,[0,T]}$, $[Y]_{\alpha,[0,T]}$ the corresponding Holder norms of $X$ and $Y$ on the interval $[0,T]$, respectively. Then the standard inequality for the Young integral implies
$$
|Y_t-Y_s-Y_s(X_t-X_s)|\le C[X]_{\beta,[0,T]}[Y]_{\alpha,[0,T]} (t-s)^{\alpha+\beta},\quad s,t\in[0,T].
$$
This in turn leads
$$
|Y_t-Y_s|\le C[X]_{\beta,[0,T]}[Y]_{\alpha,[0,T]} (t-s)^{\alpha+\beta}+|Y_s|\,|X_t-X_s|,
$$
and thus
$$
[Y]_{\beta,[0,T]}\le C[X]_{\beta,[0,T]}[Y]_{\alpha,[0,T]} T^{\alpha}+[X]_{\beta,[0,T]}\sup_{r\in[0,T]}|Y_r|.
$$

However, because $\beta<\alpha$, the last inequality gives us nothing (we are estimating a smaller norm by a larger norm). The iteration over $T$ also seems hopeless. So what to do?

Comment: Just notice that your first inequality and the condition $Y\in Hol_\alpha$ forces $X\in Hol_\alpha$ as long as $Y$ is separated from $0$.

Comment: @fedja I agree and I also thought about using this fact, but unfortunately I don't see how it helps. It might be that $X$ is alpha Holder on any interval $[\epsilon,1]$ (with its Holder norm going to infinity as $\epsilon$ approaches $0$) and still not alpha Holder on $[0,1]$. Think about $\sqrt x$. Its Lipschitz on any interval $[\epsilon,1]$, but not Lipschitz on $[0,1]$. Maybe I am missing something here, but the proof definitely does not follow immediately from your comment. Do you have a formal proof or could you please expand your ideas?

Comment: "Maybe I am missing something here, but the proof definitely does not follow immediately from your comment." It does. Let $t>0$. Choose small $\varepsilon>0$ and consider the last moment $t_1\in[0,t]$ when $|Y_t|\le\varepsilon$. Then $|Y_s|\ge\varepsilon$ on $[t_1,t]$, so $X\in Hol_\alpha([t_1,t])$ and then $Y_s=Y_{t_1}\exp(X_s-X_{t_1})$ for $s\in[t_1,t]$. In particular $|Y_t|\le\varepsilon\exp(2\|X\|_{C([0,t])})$. But $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrarily small!

Comment: @fedja thanks! that's indeed a great solution. If you would formally post is as a solution, I would be very happy to award you the promised bounty.

Comment: I was hoping though that one can solve this problem by iterating the inequalities I wrote. My motivation is that i am stuck with a similar problem, but for PDEs. I want to show that dY/dt=\Delta Y+YdX  has a unique zero solution (where now Y=Y(x,t)) under the same regularity assumptions. In this case one cannot write the solutions explicitly, but one can get very similar bounds to the ones presented in my question.

Comment: Then just ask a separate question with full details and I (or somebody else) will try to answer. Just make sure that you describe the space in which you are looking for $Y$ precisely :-)

Comment: As stated this is not true. For example let $X(t)=t$ and $Y(t)=e^t$. Then $X\in C^{.6}$ and $Y\in C^{.1}$. You probably need some kind of NOT Holder condition.

Comment: @user479223 sorry I forgot to mention that we fix the initial condition Y(0)=0.

Comment: @Oleg The RDE forces the regularity of Yt to also be less than 1/2. You cannot impose a different regularity.

Comment: @ThomasKojar What do you mean I cannot impose a different regularity? Of course I can, this is the whole point of the question. If we know in advance that $Y$ is very regular, show that $Y$ is identically zero (or provide a counter-example).

Comment: @ThomasKojar Let me rephrase my question. We are given two processes. $Y$ which is very regular and $X$ which is less regular. It is known that $dY_t=Y_td X_t$ (in the usual ODE, not RDE sense, all the integrals are well-defined Young integrals). Question: is it true that $Y\equiv0$?

Comment: @ThomasKojar: no it is possible. If $Y=0$, $X=t^\alpha$, then regularity of $0$ is infinity, and regularity of $X$ is $\alpha$ which can be as small as possible. Again: we are __given___ two processes $X$ and $Y$ with this properties. Given. Someone gave them to me. Question: is it true that $Y$ is identically $0$, and why?

Comment: @Oleg I updated the question

Comment: In other words: I am asking for uniqueness only among $C^\alpha$ solutions (not among all solutions) for which we can always define this as a Young integral. Is it more clear now?

Comment: @ThomasKojar I really do not understand what you do not understand in my question. We are given two processes $Y$ and $X$, $Y$ is regular $X$ is not. They solve a certain equation. Question: does this mean that $Y=0$ or there is another _regular_ process $\widetilde Y$ such that $d\widetilde Y=\widetilde Y dX$. You are asking a different question, but which part in my question you do not understand? I am talking here about standard ODEs not RDEs. You are trying to answer a different question.

Comment: @ThomasKojar I agree with Oleg. You are not paying attention to the question that is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

We will follow the Lemma 8.10. (Rough Gronwall) and Proposition 8.12 from "a course in rough paths" but modify them for this particular setting of studying

$$Y_{t}=Y_{0}+\int^{t}_{0} Y dX,$$

for $Y\in C^{\alpha},X\in C^{\beta}$ where $\alpha+\beta>1$ but $\beta<\frac{1}{2}$ and $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$.

The Lemma 8.10. (Rough Gronwall) comes verbatim with no changes

> Assume $Y\in C([0,1])$, $r<1$ and
> $$|Y_{s,t}|\leq M ||Y||_{\infty;[s,t]}|t-s|^{r},(*)$$
> for $0\leq s< t\leq 1$. Then there exists $c=c_{r}<\infty$ such that
> $$||Y||_{\infty;[0,1]}\leq cexp(cM^{1/r})|Y_{0}|.$$

So it suffices to prove (*). From a slight variation of the proof of Proposition 8.12 we have the bound

$$|Y_{s,t}|=|\int_{s}^{t}Y_{r}dX_{r}|\leq c||Y||_{\infty;[s,t]}||X||_{\beta;[s,t]}|t-s|^{\beta}\leq c||Y||_{\infty;[s,t]}|t-s|^{\beta},$$
where we used that $\beta<\frac{1}{2}\leq \alpha$ and so $||Y||_{\alpha;[s,t]}\leq ||Y||_{\beta;[s,t]}$. So the result follows from here.